# MongoDb group by two conditions in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I would like to group my data by different conditions but I do not understand how I could do it.

My data:

```
[
 {"Id": "1", "Info": "X" "Date": 10/1},
 {"Id": "2", "Info": "X" "Date": 13/2},
 {"Id": "3", "Info": "Y" "Date": 13/2},
 {"Id": "4", "Info": "X" "Date": 10/1},
 {"Id": "5", "Info": "X" "Date": 10/1},
 {"Id": "6", "Info": "X" "Date": 13/2},
]
```

And I would like to group them by Info and by Date, a result similar to this one:

```
[
 {"Id": ["1","4","5"], "Info": "X" "Date": 10/1},
]
[ 
 {"Id": ["2", "6"], "Info": "X" "Date": 13/2},
 ]   
[
 {"Id": ["3"], "Info": "Y" "Date": 13/2},
]
```

I am using `aggregate` and I just know how to use aggregate to group them just by one condition, I don´t know how to continue and how to use `date` in `$group`, this is what I have and how I group it by info:

```
.aggregate([
            { "$match" : { "$or": [{"status": "downloading"}, {"status": "calculating"}]}},
            { "$project": {"Id": 1, "Date": 1, "info": 1}},
            { "$group" : { "_id" : "$Info", "Id" : { "$addToSet" : "$Id"}}},
            { "$project": {"_id": 0, "Info": "$_id", "Id": 1 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `_id` in the `$group` stage multiple fields, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Id": 1,
      "Date": 1,
      "info": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        date: "$Date",
        info: "$info"
      },
      "Id": {
        "$addToSet": "$Id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Info": "$_id.info",
      "Date": "$_id.date",
      "Id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1OXe4_P3v4R)